# Project Euler 21: Sum of Amicable Numbers

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x

[Problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21):

> Let \$d(n)\$ be defined as the sum of proper divisors of \$n\$ (numbers less than \$n\$ which divide evenly into \$n\$).
>   If \$d(a) = b\$ and \$d(b) = a\$, where \$a ≠ b\$, then \$a\$ and \$b\$ are an amicable pair and each of \$a\$ and \$b\$ are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore \$d(220) = 284\$. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so \$d(284) = 220\$.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

Am I abusing reduce or itertools here? I'm concerned this solution could be more readable. Also, is there a more efficient solution rather than calculating everything up front?

```
from itertools import chain, count
from operator import mul

def factorize(n):
    for factor in chain((2,), count(start=3,step=2)):
        if factor*factor > n:
            break

        exp = 0
        while n % factor == 0:
            exp += 1
            n //= factor
        if exp > 0:
            yield factor, exp

    if n > 1:
        yield n, 1

def sum_of_factors(n):
    """
    >>> sum_of_factors(220)
    284
    >>> sum_of_factors(284)
    220
    """
    total = reduce(mul,
        ((fac**(exp+1)-1)/(fac-1) for fac,exp in factorize(n)),
        1)
    return total - n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache = {k: sum_of_factors(k)
        for k in xrange(1, 10000)
    }

    print sum(k for k, v in cache.iteritems()
        if cache.get(v, None) == k
        and v != k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks nice but I have a few suggestions to make it easier to understand **according to my personal preferences**.

---

It might be worth defining a function to encapsulate your call to `reduce` and `mul` (if you go forward in Project Euler problems, you'll reuse it many times) :

```
def mult(iterable, start=1):
    """Returns the product of an iterable - like the sum builtin."""
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, iterable, start)
```

That you can easily use :

```
def sum_of_factors(n):
    """
    >>> sum_of_factors(220)
    284
    >>> sum_of_factors(284)
    220
    """
    total = mult((fac**(exp+1)-1)/(fac-1) for fac,exp in factorize(n))
    return total - n
```

---

Your function `factorize` generates tuples of the form `(prime factor, power)` which is probably worth documenting (either in the doc or in the function name).

I think it'd be easier to generate prime factors without grouping them as this can be delegated to a different function.

You'd have something like :

```
def factorize(n):
    """Generate prime factors (potentially repeated) in order."""
    for factor in chain((2,), count(start=3,step=2)):
        if factor*factor > n:
            break

        while n % factor == 0:
            n //= factor
            yield factor
    if n > 1:
        yield n
```

This function does one thing (and does it well) and can be easily tested :

```
for i in range(1, 1000):
    fact = list(factorize(i))
    assert mult(fact) == i  # see, i've reused mult already :-)
    assert sorted(fact) == fact  # there was a time where I needed that property but it's not really important now
```

Grouping and counting can be delected to a [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
def sum_of_factors(n):
    """
    >>> sum_of_factors(220)
    284
    >>> sum_of_factors(284)
    220
    """
    total = mult((fac**(exp+1)-1)/(fac-1) for fac,exp in collections.Counter(factorize(n)).items())
    return total - n
```

---

The function `sum_of_factors` probably deserves some additional explanation (especially because the name says `sum` while the code says `mult`). Maybe a link to [some reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) would be enough.

---

You can avoid a few cache lookups. Indeed, at the moment, you consider all pairs (a, b) with a != b and add a whenever you find one. You could limit yourself to pairs (a, b) with a < b and add a+b when you find it. Also, by doing so, you know for sure that the value you are looking for will be in the cache.

```
sum_facts = {k: sum_of_factors(k) if k else 0 for k in range(10000) }
print(sum(k + v for k, v in sum_facts.items() if v < k and sum_facts[v] == k))
```

Comment: I guess since the factors will be sorted, you could just use `groupby` instead of `Counter`.  Last suggestion is solid.

Comment: `groupby` would work indeed but it is slightly more complicated to use and I couldn't be bothered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Why U No Doctest `factorize()`?

You wrote a doctest for `sum_of_divisors`, but why'd you forget about `factorize()`? Just because it's a generator doesn't mean you can't doctest it:

```
def factorize(n):
    """ 
    >>> list(factorize(10))
    [(2, 1), (5, 1)]
    >>> list(factorize(360))
    [(2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 1)]
    >>> list(factorize(991))
    [(991, 1)]
    """
    ...
```